# Error while accessing nested JSON object

Tags: rethinkdb

This is a sample row in my RethinkDB table.

```
 {
  "a1":  "val1" ,
  "a2":  "val2" ,
  "a3":  "val3" ,
  "a4":  "val4" ,
  "part": [
  {
  "id":  "reql" ,
  "position":  "student"
  } ,
 {
 "id":  "sdsadda" ,
 "position":  "officer"
 }
 ] ,
 "a5":  "val5" 

 }
```

I want to access a nested json object but I get the error e: Cannot perform bracket on a non-object non-sequence `"string"` 
I need the entire row in the output for rows matching id to "reql"
This is my query

`r.db('dbname').table('tablename').filter(r.row('part').contains(function(product) {
    return product('id').eq("reql");
}))`

This query worked before .It doesn't right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd get that error if you'd somehow ended up with an element in your `part` array that's a string instead of an object.  Try running `.filter(r.row('part').contains(function(product) { return product.typeOf().ne('OBJECT'); })`, that should return all the rows that have a string in the `part` array.

Comment: Is it possible to write a query which gives results in spite of id being string in some row and object in all others?

Comment: You could replace the body of your `contains` with something like `product.typeOf().eq('OBJECT').and(product('id').eq('reql'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment @Puja, I think this should do it for you:

```
r.db('dbname').table('tablename').filter(function(d){
    d("part").typeOf().eq("ARRAY");
}).filter(r.row('part').contains(function(d) {
    return d('id').eq("reql");
}))
```

Although, this is less efficient than @mlucy's answer, and you should definitely just do the one pass over your dataset to clean it up by fixing all the documents where `part: STRING`.